# How to display data from one page to another in gridview on button click by using session on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages, buttonclick

Thanx in advance.
I'm facing issue in transfering data from gridview of home page to another search reasult page. page showing blank only.no data displaying.
Im using with master page.
Im trying to fetch data from textbox for search result like source and destination  from textbox.

## for refernce please find below code of home.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IT_APPS_SUPP;Initial Catalog=dotnet;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        con.Open();
        string str1 = "Select * from busbooking where zone='" + txtSourceBus.Text + "' " + "and destination='" + txtDestBus.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str1, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Label1.Text = "";          
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            GridView1.Visible = true;
            dr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Data not  found";
        }

        DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;//set the datasource
        Session["GridData"] = dt;
        Response.Redirect("~/BusSearch.aspx",true);
    }
```

=========================================================

### bussearch.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["GridData"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

==================================================================
can anyone help for this., my second page showing blank only.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing DataSet instead  of DataTable like this

```
Session["GridData"] = ds.Tables[0];
```

All the other code can stay as it is.

Comment: I won't advise that "All the other code can stay as it is". He isn't using prepared statements to construct his sql query. This can be dangerous because of SQL injection

Comment: Ok yes, I agree but for  the puropse of passing the values from one page to another page the existing code works and it does not need changing, however it would be good to at least use parameters in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use like this
In bussearch.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["GridData"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = Session["GridData"] as DataTable;
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for u r valuable reply @Vineet Dwivedi